# the best index when having two timestamp columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have two columns in my MySQL Database start_time and end_time. They both are TIMESTAMP. I have created an index on the two columns.

I have 3.5 million rows. This query takes 13s to be executed :

```
select * from test WHERE start_time > TIMESTAMP('2020-04-02 09:00:00') and end_time < TIMESTAMP('2020-04-02 10:00:00')
```

Is there any way to optimise it ?

**EDIT:**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `YYY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `start_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `end_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `index1` (`YYY`,`start_time`) USING BTREE,
 UNIQUE KEY `index2` (`YYY`,`start_time`,`end_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Don't really know, i found it as solution in some questions.

Comment: What do you mean by your second reply ?

Comment: Ooh, i made a mistake it's actually end_time <

Comment: You can only use one index at a time, so the index on endtime (which, presumably, can be NULL) is less useful than the index on starttime (which, presumably, cannot be null). But a composite index on both might be most useful (once you get rid of those nonsense functions)

Comment: I'm using a composite index. When i got rid of the two functions the query is taking time to execute but the result tells me that it took 0.000 seconds ! Is that normal ?

Comment: I made an edit for the question. Apparently, the index was not used.

Comment: I made an edit. You should note that I added YYY column in the index to make the index unique. I tried to use a composite index for only start_time and end_time but it was too slow to be executed

Comment: "0.000 seconds" sounds like the Query cache was on.  Use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid such ridiculously fast, irrelevant, timings.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this finding:

```
EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT *
    ->   FROM test
    ->  WHERE start_time >= '2020-04-02 09:00:00'
    ->    AND end_time <= '2020-04-02 10:00:00';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | index | NULL          | index2 | 267     | NULL | 262035 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Actually, I'm surprised that the index is used, given that YYY is not part of the filtering condition. Anyway, try without YYY, or try with YYY as the third argument in the index. And remove the other indices.

Comment: In my query the index was not used. I tried index with this order (start_time, end_time) but was not faster (This index can't be unique). However, I tried this order (start_time, YYY, end_time) and it's working like a charm. I don't know why, but i'll let it like this and when I find a solution I'll write it as an answer. The YYY column help me use UNIQUE Index, whitout it I cannot set Index as UNIQUE.

Comment: Did you leave `yyy` out of your test?  `Using index` implies that `*` does not include any extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother having one `UNIQUE` (index2) that starts with the same column as another `UNIQUE` (index1).

There is no index (in MySQL, at least) that optimizes for such an "overlap" test.

If you the time ranges are non-overlapping (that is, no two pairs of start..end overlap other than one `end` matches another `start), then my technique for IP-ranges scales quite well.  But it requires restructuring the table.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges